# How to add photo frame over an image?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, android-image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gF5O.jpg)

How to add this type of frame in android over an image like the picture given

Answer (score -1):

> If you are searching for custom border and shape of ImageView
>    [Try this](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview)

or

> set the below XML to the background of the Image View as Drawable. It works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>

And then add android:background="@drawable/yourXmlFileName" to your ImageView
```

Comment: did you see the image background in my picture? like that i m trying to implement